# ajax show alerts if record is added

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created two alerts, on successful AddStaff a success alert should appear, if the a staff coulld not be able to added then warning alert should appear. This is what i have done:

```
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none" id="AddLateStudentAlert"><div class="alert alert-warnning" style="display: none" id="WarningAlert">
```

This is my ajax that add Staff

```
function AddStaff(Staff) {
        ajReq.abort();
        ajReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/Staff.asmx/Staff",
            data: "{'Staff':'" + Staff+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (msg) {

                $('#SucessAlert').show();
                $("#AddLateStudentAlert").fadeOut(5000);

            },else:(!sucess) {
                $('#WarningAlert').show();
    }
```

The alert dose not work, when adding a staff, it always shows warning alert. can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function AddStaff(Staff) {
    ajReq.abort();
    ajReq = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/Staff.asmx/Staff",
        data: "{'Staff':'" + Staff+ "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (msg) {

            $('#SucessAlert').show();
            $("#AddLateStudentAlert").fadeOut(5000);

        },
        error:function() {
            $('#WarningAlert').show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `error` as `else` isn't a valid function of `$.ajax`. See jQuery's **[AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**.

Example:

```
success: function (msg) {

            $('#SucessAlert').show();
            $("#AddLateStudentAlert").fadeOut(5000);

        },
error: function(msg) {
            $('#WarningAlert').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `else` callback in [jQuery.ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Use error **callback**

```
       success: function (msg) {
            $('#SucessAlert').show();
            $("#AddLateStudentAlert").fadeOut(5000);
        },
       error:(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ) {
              console.log(errorThrown)
            $('#WarningAlert').show();
       }
```